# How to create a swagger:response that produces a binary application/pdf file?

Tags: python-3.x, openapi, swagger-codegen, content-disposition, connexion

I'm failing in getting a file download working in swagger, connexion, openapi3. Within the openapi specification I've defined the following path:

```
/lab/samples/list/pdf:
get: 
  summary: download pdf file
  operationId: get_sample_pdf
  responses:
    "200":
        application/pdf:
          schema:
            type: string
            format: binary  
  security:
  - labuserAuth: []
  x-openapi-router-controller: swagger_server.controllers.lab_controller#
```

The call is forwarded to my lab_controler.py which simplay returns the binary pdf

```
def list_sample_pdf():
    f_pdf = "list_samples.pdf"
    with open(f_pdf, "rb") as f:
        return f.read()
```

When calling the endpoint I receive

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

As I was looking for answers I stumbled upon a bunch of different threads, but non of them could really give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong

- [Download Excel file from a link as a response from Open Api 3](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5750)
- [Does swagger-codegen drop the `format: binary` from the model for `type: string`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2305#issuecomment-616533375)
- is manually setting the Content-Disposition headers required? Or are they added by connexion?
- [How to define a swagger:response that produces a binary file, application/octet-stream](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/1003)

What configurations are required on the openapi side? And what should my controller implementation be retourning, so that connexion is able to properly handle the pdf?

This is how I run the application

```
    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
    app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'sample-submission and notification service'}, pythonic_params=True)

    #add CORS support to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
    CORS(app.app,expose_headers=["Content-Disposition: "])
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8083)
```

I also tried adding an application/octet-stream response

```
application/octet-stream:
                  encoding:
                    file:
                      headers:
                        Content-Disposition:
                          schema:
                            type: string
                            format: binary
                            example: attachment; filename="name.pdf"
```

When instead of returning a pdf file, `with open(f_csv, "rb") as f: return f.read()` a UTF-8 readable file as this simple csv file, te the content of the non binary file is returned by connexion as application/json response

Comment: Add the `content:` node between `"200":` and `application/pdf:` in the response definition. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a [header definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62745088)?

```
paths:          
  /examples:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
          content:
            application/pdf:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
          headers:
            Content-Disposition:
              schema:
                type: string
                description: Used only with `application/pdf` responses
                example: attachment; filename="name.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/

```
paths:
 get:
  summary: Returns the report in the PDF format
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A PDF file
      content:
        application/pdf:
          schema:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

Answer (score 0):

I use NSWAG to create the client code automatically from the MapGet.

```
    builder.MapGet(
        "download/{path}",
        async ( string path) =>
        {
            var mimeType = "audio/wav";
            return Results.File(path);

        })
        .Produces(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
        .Produces((int)StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(FileResult))
        .WithName($"GET {EndPointName} by Name")
        .WithTags(EndPointTag);
```

Answer (score -1):

as a non very elegant workaround you can do the following to return :

```
 import flask, os
    
    resp = flask.send_from_directory(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), 'file_to_send.pdf',
            as_attachment=True, 
            mimetype='application/pdf',
            attachment_filename='your_pdf_name.pdf'
        )

    return flask.Response(
            response = resp.response,
            status=200,
            content_type='application/pdf',
            headers=resp.headers,
            mimetype=resp.mimetype
        )
```