# OpenAPI- Provide a link to download response's examples in pdf (adding examples for pdf)

Tags: json, download, response, openapi, attachment

In Openapi, response's example which is in pdf need to be provided as download link in Swagger UI/Redoc etc.

I am using OpenAPI 3.1 and for one of API. I need to show example of response as pdf file which is hosted(locally) based on [External Examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/). It could be a link for downloading PDF in UIs. After trying various methods I am unable to get link to download file in Swagger UI as well as in Redoc UI.

I am using JSON based OpenAPI. I have referred [Open API 3 - add headers on individual content-type in responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739261/open-api-3-add-headers-on-individual-content-type-in-responses) and implement it in JSON. But in my case i am unable to make it work.

Sample is as follows:

```
"/myapplication/pdfresponse": { 
"get": { 
    "responses": { 
        "200": { 
                "description": "PDF format response.",      
                "content": {
                  "application/pdf": {
                  "schema":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "format":"binary"
                    },
                  "examples":{ 
                    "exampleName":{
                        "summary":"PDF format.",
                        "externalValue": "examples/abc.pdf"
                    } 
                   }
                  } 
                },
                "headers":{
                  "Content-Disposition":{
                    "schema":{
                      "type": "string",
                      "example": "attachment; filename=abc.pdf"               
                      } 
                    } 
                  }          
               }
              }
```

Probably headers content-disposition is wrong or something else is required. Please provide sample of JSON or let me know if I am missing something. Thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is to provide a download url of the pdf document.

You need to use `externalValue` and provide the <string> as a `uri` of the download location

This probably won't work unless you host the file somewhere else other than local. I have a feeling cors will block this request on a local instance of the ui.

I know as of writing, Redoc does not resolve `externalValue` uris. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/Redocly/redocly-cli/issues/919) if you want to comment, contribute or otherwise stay up to date on the progress of it.

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.1.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "test api",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/api/v1/thing": {
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "thing",
                        "headers": {
                            "content-disposition": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "examples": {
                                    "sample_header": {
                                        "value": "application/pdf; attachment; filename: sample.pdf"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "content": {
                            "application/pdf": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "format": "binary"
                                },
                                "examples": {
                                    "pdf_example": {
                                        "summary": "a download link for a pdf",
                                        "externalValue": "file://C:\\Users\/<user>\/Downloads\/1testing.pdf"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it gives response which is getting displayed as kind of stream text. Swagger UI and Redoc is unable to render inline pdf. So is it possible to download this received stream as pdf by displaying "Download file" option referring [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4250#issuecomment-368990571)

Comment: If you read the comment on that issue, you need to use content-disposition header with attachment parameter.   I updated the answer to include it.   Not sure if it works with redoc though

Comment: Yes I have added content-disposition header as per your suggested code. But no luck in Redoc as well as Swagger UI to get a downloadable pdf link.

Comment: I would suggest raising a ticket on both of their github repos.

Comment: Ok Thanks.....!